# Scala multiple with

Tags: scala, traits

New to Scala. The language is quite concise.

Curious why implementing multiple traits requires multiple "with" statements.

For example:

```
class Foo extends Bar with A with B with C {}
```

vs.

```
class Foo extends Bar with A, B, C {}
```

Comment: if you're going that route, why have "with" at all?  Why not `Class Foo extends Bar, A, B, C`?

Comment: again, new to scala, but afaik multiple inheritance with "extends" is not supported, while "with" provides a form of such functionality

Answer (score 28, accepted):

Consider this

```
class Foo[A, B]

new Foo[Bar with D with E, Bar with E] {}
```

vs

```
new Foo[Bar with D, E, Bar with E] {}
```

It just isn’t unambiguous in all cases.

Comment: ahhh, ok, that clarifies the apparent non-DRY-ness of multiple with, thanks.

Comment: @virtualeyes You can think of `with` like a (different-looking) comma - that should make it apparent that there is no DRY violation.